# How to define Base Url in core php

Tags: php, routes

Well, I am working on core php, I am unable to define a constant base URL for my application.

I am working using xampp on mac os, I have the main file initilize.php in htdocs/myproject/private directory, which contain the code to define a base URL

```
$url      = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$validURL = str_replace("&", "&amp", $url);
```

Now when I include the initialize.php file in myproject/index.php as,

```
<?php
require_once 'private/initialize.php';
header('Location: site/');
```

I got BASE_URL as http://localhost/myproject/site , but when I include the initilize.php file in the site/create.php I got the BASE_URL as 
http://localhost/myproject/site/create.php, I am unable to define a base URL for myproject, which in xampp case is localhost/myproject and after deployment it must be http://subdomain.myproject.com any suggestion in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I defined it, `define("BASE_URL", $validURL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve my problem by using the following piece of code

```
/*
 * Assign the root URL to a PHP constant
 * Do not need to include the domain
 * Use same document root as web server
 * Can dynamically find everything in URL up to "/site"
 */
$site_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/site') + 5;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $site_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
$url      = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . WWW_ROOT;
$validURL = str_replace("&", "&amp", $url);
define("BASE_URL", $validURL);
```

It always return BASE_URL = http://localhost/myproject/site

Comment: Using `HTTP_HOST` is not secure because `Host` header can be spoofed. @Hasta Dhana's solution uses `SERVER_NAME` which is more secure as this will come from your server configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a static *base_url* for your `myproject` directory like this :

```php
$protocol   = if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$servername = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'SERVER_NAME');
$url        = $protocol . $servername;
if (strstr($servername, 'localhost')) {
   $url        .= '/myproject/'; // add project directory on localhost setup
}
$validURL   = str_replace("&", "&amp", $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using environmental variables (.env files or apache/nginx configuration) or you can set it manually as shown below, there is no magic which can find a base url on your localhost if you the /myproject part to it.

```
$protocol = if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$baseUrl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (strstr($baseUrl, 'localhost')) {
   $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/myproject/site';
}
```